# git checkout commit and then making it the base

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

I'm on a branch called `A`..

the branch `A` has two commits, with the following codes: `commit1` and `commit2` where the most recent is `commit2`.

i just noticed i want to go back to `commit1` because in `commit2` I deleted a file I needed and i wrote some useless code.. i want to go back to `commit1` so i do `git checkout commit1`

on the terminal it now says i'm here: `$ git:(commit1)` but what I expected was  `$ git:(A)`

i'm not sure how to make `commit1` my base for the the branch.

is it `git revert`? `git reset`? I've read the docs but I'm not quite sure what to do

Comment: What exactly do you want? Discard commit2 permanently? Apparently according to your comment below. Do you want to insert some changes between commit1 and commit2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove your commit2 permanently then do `git reset --hard <commit1-id>`

This will take to commit1 in branch A.

Comment: is there a way to not delete it so that I can switch back to it after I finished a test for example?

Comment: git reset --soft <commit1-id>